# calling echo $this->action('panLogin','user') and $this->action('panRegister','user') on same script

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have a problem, i'm trying to render 2 forms (login and register) on one layout scrpt (header.phtml), every time i submit on one of the forms both actions for the controller are getting fired and i'm unsure how to fix it.

The forms are getting rendered fine within the layout, however when you click 'Login' or 'Register' on the forms the code fires in both the 'login' and 'register actions.

the header layout script snippet:-

```
 <div class="left">
   <h1>Already a member? <br>Then Login!</h1>
     <?php
        echo $this->action('panlogin', 'user');
      ?>
 </div>
 <div class="left right">
 <h1>Not a member yet? <br>Get Registered!</h1>
    <?php
        echo $this->action('panregister', 'user');
    ?>       
 </div>
```

the action scripts (phtmls)

panregister.phtml

```
<div id="pan-register">
   <?php
     $this->registerForm->setAction($this->url);
     echo $this->registerForm;
   ?>
</div>
```

panlogin.phtml

```
<div id="pan-login">
   <?php
      $this->loginForm->setAction($this->url);
    ?>
</div>
```

the user controller actions:-

```
    class Ajfit_UserController extends Zend_Controller_Action
    {
       protected $_loginForm;

       protected $_registerForm;

       public function init()
       {       
          $this->_loginForm  = new Ajfit_Form_User_Login(array(
              'action' => '/user/login',
              'method' => 'post',
          ));
          $this->_registerForm = new \Ajfit\Form\User\Registration(array(
              'action' => '/user/register',
              'method' => 'post'
          ));
       }

       //REGISTER ACTIONS
       public function panregisterAction(){
           $this->registerAction();
       }

       public function registerAction(){
           $request = $this->_request;
           if ($this->_request->isPost()){
              $formData = $this->_request->getPost();
           }
           $this->view->registerForm = $this->_registerForm;
       }

       //LOGIN ACTIONS
       public function panloginAction(){
           $this->loginAction();
       }

      public function loginAction(){
         $request = $this->_request;
         if(!$auth->hasIdentity()){   
            if ($this->_request->isPost()){
               $formData = $this->_request->getPost();
            }
         }
         $this->view->loginForm = $this->_loginForm;
      }
   }
```

Please can someone with a little more knowlegde with the action('act','cont'); ?> code with in a layout script help me out with this problem.

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: I'm curious, you create $request = $this->_request; n every action but then you never seem to use it. May I ask why?

Comment: they are just inplace for degugging code, i don't use them so they can be removed :) thanks for your input mate its much apprieciated thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While David is correct where best practices are concerned, I have on occasion just added another if() statement. Kinda like this:

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
                if ($this->getRequest()->getPost('submit') == 'OK') {
```

just make sure your submit label is unique.
Eventually I'll get around to refactoring all those actions I built early in the learning process, for now though, they work.

Now to be nosy :)

I noticed: `$formData = $this->_request->getPost();` while this works, if you put any filters on your forms retrieving the data in this manner bypasses your filters. To retrieve filtered values use `$formData = $this->getValues();`

> from the ZF manual
>
> The Request Object
>   **GET and POST Data**
>   Be cautious when accessing data from the request object as it is not filtered in any way. The router and
>   dispatcher validate and filter data for use with their tasks, but
>   leave the data untouched in the request object.
>
> From Zend_Form Quickstart
>
> Assuming your validations have passed, you can now fetch the filtered
>   values:
>
> `$values = $form->getValues();`

Answer (score 0):

Don't render the *actions* in your layout. Just render the forms:

```
<div class="left">
   <h1>Already a member? <br>Then Login!</h1>
     <?php
        echo new \Ajfit\Form\User\Login(array(
          'action' => '/user/login',
          'method' => 'post'
      ));
      ?>
 </div>
 <div class="left right">
 <h1>Not a member yet? <br>Get Registered!</h1>
     <?php
        echo new \Ajfit\Form\User\Registration(array(
          'action' => '/user/register',
          'method' => 'post'
      ));
      ?>
 </div>
```

Then, whichever form gets used will post to its own action.

Comment: the layout scripts are in my indexController and my actions are in my userController, will the actions still get called?

Comment: yes, they will go to whatever action is registered in the form action using standard ZF routes. /module(if present)/controller/action